# How to concatenate column A data based on column B data

Tags: excel, formula

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I have attached one excel image...where the data is not consistent and I want to consolidate A column data in column C based on B column

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnOcu.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnOcu.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8yAb.jpg)[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You want:
Col A + Col B in col C with col C contents

Comment: Only column A data needs to be concotenated based on column B..column C is the result what I am looking out for..